# How to make this script works

Tags: javascript

```
dom.style.-webkit-transform ='rotate(-90deg)';
```

In Chrome it tell: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rotate-button')[0].style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
```

Answer (score 4):

a) The `-` char is the `subtraction operator` and is not valid for use as part of an identifier in JavaScript.

b) I would define a pre-existing CSS class that has the behavior that you want, then just append the class to the `class` attribute:

CSS:

```
.transform {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rotate-button')[0].className += ' transform';
```

Comment: B=> Ok, this is just a example, can you make this script works. But the value of transform is a variable, so i want to change it in js, not css

Comment: Also be aware that `document.getElementsByClassName` is not completely cross-compatible.

Comment: I want the class transform in js, not css

Comment: The property is `.className` by the way. And you might want to add a space to each end of `transform` to ensure two class names don't run together.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName('rotate-button')[0].style['-webkit-transform'] ='rotate(-90deg)';`

`-` is the minus operator in javascript and you can't use it in a property directly